# http://8 --> http://0.0.0.8 is a standard convention?

Tags: php, ip, ip-address

Today I found out that the command:

```
php -S 0:8888
```

starts a server on localhost just the same as:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8888
```

And also, navigating Safari to:

```
http://8
```

will redirect to:

```
http://0.0.0.8
```

Also, I found that Safari will redirect http://1.2 and http://1.2.3 in other ways.

---

Is there any documented standard or convention that explains this, or did I find a similar easter egg in two different softwares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not official official, but it's an RFC draft which is pretty close. It doesn't define this behaviour, but it mentions it and sort of legitimizes it.

> Meanwhile, a very popular implementation of IP networking went off in
> its own direction.  4.2BSD introduced a function inet_aton(), whose
> job was to interpret character strings as IP addresses.  It
> interpreted both of the syntaxes mentioned in [MTP] (see above): a
> single number giving the entire 32-bit address, and dot-separated
> octet values.  It also interpreted two intermediate syntaxes: octet-
> dot-octet-dot-16bits, intended for class B addresses, and octet-
> dot-24bits, intended for class A addresses.  It also allowed some
> flexibility in how the individual numeric parts were specified: it
> allowed octal and hexadecimal in addition to decimal, distinguishing
> these radices by using the C language syntax involving a prefix "0"
> or "0x", and allowed the numbers to be arbitrarily long.

> The 4.2BSD inet_aton() has been widely copied and imitated, and so is
> a de facto standard for the textual representation of IPv4 addresses.
> Nevertheless, these alternative syntaxes have now fallen out of use
> (if they ever had significant use).  The only practical use that they
> now see is for deliberate obfuscation of addresses: giving an IPv4
> address as a single 32-bit decimal number is favoured among people
> wishing to conceal the true location that is encoded in a URL.  All
> the forms except for decimal octets are seen as non-standard (despite
> being quite widely interoperable) and undesirable.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02

---

And, we can see this code still lives to this day:

> a single number giving the entire 32-bit address

```
❱ ping 2321319336
PING 2321319336 (138.92.133.168): 56 data bytes
...
```

> octet- dot-octet-dot-16bits, intended for class B addresses

```
❱ ping 172.16.2342
PING 172.16.2342 (172.16.9.38): 56 data bytes
....
```

> octet-dot-24bits, intended for class A addresses

```
❱ ping 10.45253
PING 10.45253 (10.0.176.197): 56 data bytes
...
```

---

Note that [RFC 3896 explicitly defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-49) an IP address in a URI as the dotted quad decimal representation, so technically speaking these shortcuts are not allowed in URIs at all!

Comment: Excellent reference, thank you. I also found section "7.4.  Rare IP Address Formats" in there. Also I see that `http://1.0xf` will resolve as well.

Answer (score 0):

An IPv4 address is an unsigned 32-bit integer. The dotted by-byte notation is just a more (human-)readable variant - very often you can use both notations interchangeably:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping ‭134744072‬
```